# When will we appoint pro-tem moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Having read [this blogpost](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/27/moderator-pro-tempore/), I wonder when we will appoint pro-tem Moderators.

The first post states that the nomination should begin approximately 2 weeks after the private beta begins (and 12 days is approximately two weeks):

> If your meta site does not have a post to nominate Moderators, start one now! Pro Tem appointments will begin **about two weeks after the site is created**. The more guidance we receive, the more informed our choice

<sup>(highlighted by mee)</sup>

I don't know whether it may be a bit too early for this but this page should go public in about 5 days (stated on the message informing visitors about the private beta of this page) and I suppose @RobertCartaino and the community team won't complain if they get some pro-tem moderators to help them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nominations typically start about two weeks into the private beta. **It has not been two weeks.**

I will likely post a call for nominations this coming Monday or Tuesday. No need to start one yourself; we have already optimized that post.

Also note that private betas currently run a full *three* weeks. We have also radically lowered the bar for what it means to be in private beta (versus a fully public site), so if you know anyone who needs to be here helping build this thing, **the time to get their support is RIGHT NOW!**

Comment: Ok. Didn’t know that this blog post is no longer supported. Just wondering that the Äther post says once one week and once two weeks.

Comment: I closed this post as an duplicate of the nomination thread you just posted.