# Inviting new users

Tags: discussion

In a [recent post](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97/when-will-we-appoint-pro-tem-moderators), Robert Cartaino said

> if you know anyone who needs to be here helping build this thing, **the time to get their support is RIGHT NOW!**

This immediately made me think of [Peter Shor](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/198/peter-shor) who in fact has a stack exchange account. However, the "email private beta invite" thing doesn't allow for stack exchange accounts, just emails. How would I best go about inviting him? Are there other users on SE we should be inviting? Are there people off of SE we should be inviting?

Please, list your thoughts!

Comment: Perhaps someone is able to visit the website of the man and bother to email.

Comment: @Discretelizard There is also the matter of doing it in a non-spammy way.

Comment: Perhaps someone knows the man personally and is polite? Do mention here, than it is more likely to be a single mail.

Comment: @Discretelizard this is incoherent and also seems mildly offensive. Please take it easy.

Comment: @heather yeah, this is too much. Sorry about that.

Comment: As a point of interest we have a Blog post announcing our existence: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/03/27/quantum-computing-site-launches-with-the-help-of-strangeworks/?cb=1

Comment: I've visited MO & theoretical.CS.SE and invited the top dozen or more users whom have the highest reputation for the quantum-computing tag on those sites, either by comments or using our 'Invite Box' and their email addresses; so others ought to avoid duplicating that effort (and accusations of SPAM). ;) - Someone want to try physics ...

Comment: I put in a request to allow StackExchange accounts to be used and Dr. Shor has joined us (so no need to send another invite). My 'invitation campaign' paid off, I recognize the names of some of our newest members.