# Accepting Nominations — Who should Moderate♦ this site?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Ideally, Moderators♦ are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election, we will be appointing three provisional Moderators to fill those roles.

We need your help. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **Nominees!** Please indicate your acceptance by editing the answer to accept/decline the nomination. And please ensure your profile email is correct so we can contact you. Optionally, you are encouraged to write a bit about yourself following your acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

Comment: Note that this search should return all nominations that do not contain the word declined: [**not-declined nominations**](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A117+is%3Aa+-decline) *(revised)*

Comment: I noticed that we have at least 15 [Diamond Moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role) on our site. Is it correct that they are currently moderators here?

Comment: @Rob they are [Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do) or developers working for Stack Exchange

Comment: @Blue Yes, it should be this week or early next.

Comment: @RobertCartaino: Why is this marked as a duplicate?

Comment: @user1271772 It directs users to the answer/results of “who should moderate this site” and stops accepting new answers/nominations here.

Comment: @RobertCartaino: Surely these won't necessarily be the moderators for the entire duration of the beta (which could last several hundred days), when might they change?

Answer (score 33):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This user is the eye of the storm. This PhD students knows how to keep the calm. Excellent mod material

---

TO Mithrandir: >would you accept your nomination?...

>y/n

I accept this nomination. Thanks!

- I live in the UK, so am in either the UTC or UTC+1 time zone, depending on the time of the year. I tend to be most active during the evening to late evening.
- I'm a PhD student working on (the theoretical side of) simulations on a (photonic) quantum processor. I also have interests in open systems/noise, benchmarking, communication and networks (although I don't know as much about comms and networks) as well as a fair few other areas.
- I did my Bachelor's in physics and computer science. More physics than CS though. In my final year of this, I started looking at quantum computing and superconducting quantum computers. I followed this up with a Master's in mathematical physics.
- I'm an occasional user of IBM's quantum experience and have also started using Q#.
- I also have other interests, such as cooking and I play a few musical instruments. There are also some, more obscure interests such as Historical European Martial Arts (HEMA).
- I've also been a member of Worldbuilding SE for a couple of years and have posted the occasional answer in Physics SE as well as Science Fiction and Fantasy SE (mostly on the Valyrian language).

Of course, feel free to ask any questions in the comment section below.

Comment: Let me tell one more thing. Mithrandir is almost the only active user here wise enough not to argue with me when I was mad on non-issues! Truly, wiser than me and other candidates!

Comment: Mithrandir24601 has always seemed reasonable and fair when I interact with them in chat... and everyone gets confused because they mix us up ;). Tries to keep things calm, and is as far as I can tell rather level-headed. Also, a Tolkien fan, which is always a plus (bonus points - who am I?).

Answer (score 22):

[image]

[image]

I am self-nominating. I have participated in the review queues, meta, and the main site and am in the top six for reputation. I also have a lot of experience on other sites - for example, on Physics.SE my reputation is over 5,900, and I have over 1,000 reputation on four sites (including P.SE) and close to 1,000 rep on a fifth and sixth. On Physics.SE in particular, I am on the leaderboard for close reviews and have participated a lot on meta, so hopefully this shows that I have some background with stack exchange. I've also advertised this site on reddit and started supporting it on Area 51 when it was early in the definition phase.

Some examples of my posts include:

- [What cryogenic systems are suitable for superconducting qubits?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/41/what-cryogenic-systems-are-suitable-for-superconducting-qubits)
- [Why must quantum computers be kept near absolute zero?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/105/why-must-quantum-computers-be-kept-near-absolute-zero/110#110)
- [Are resource request questions allowed?](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/are-resource-request-questions-allowed/31#31)
- [Inviting new users](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100/inviting-new-users)

all of which are highly upvoted by the community (both meta and main site questions and answers). I'm the fourth most active user on meta. In terms of reviews, on P.SE, for example, I have done over 2,000 close vote reviews alone in less than a year, and I have similarly high stats in other queues. I'd be more than happy to put in similar amounts of time here.

A little bit about myself: I'm a highschool student who is very interested in physics and quantum computing in particular. I'm in advanced math and stuff in school, but I make no claim to be nearly as knowledgeable as many of the people on this site. I live in Iowa, so in the central time zone, or UTC-6, if I did that right. I generally participate in the evenings on weekdays and on the weekends in the mornings/afternoons. Feel free to read about what I'm currently researching on my profile page.

If anyone has any questions about me or anything to say really, please feel free to comment or ping me in the chat room.

Comment: Let me add that while we have had some (bad) words, I think you've handled matter respectfully and I wouldn't be dissatisfied if you will become a mod.

Comment: I'll add that all I've seen on [cseducators.se] shows me that Heather is an excellent candidate. Good luck!

Answer (score 17):

[image]

[image]

I accept this nomination.

I am a researcher in the field of quantum computation, currently a Research Fellow at the University of Basel. My main focus has been on quantum error correction and topological quantum computing. I've been in the field of quantum computation for over a decade now, and so have gotten a fairly good knowledge of the field. I'm also an early adopter of the new cloud based systems and SDKs, so I am hopefully not too bogged down with tradition. As a mod, I could bring sage wisdom and experience ;) .

Even so, I probably wouldn't be as active as some others might be. I'd typically expend a certain amount of time around 09:00 UTC each week day on moderation tasks, but that's about all I can commit to.

#### Notes from nominator:

While the other nominees are highly motivated, their answers and questions sometimes show, that they do not see the big picture, yet. At least one of the three mods should be an expert in the field. James' posts are of very high quality, and he is consistently active since he joined (at a later time).

Comment: Yes, it would indeed be useful to have a mod that is also expert in the field. However, such users are often busy and likely decline the offer. Also note that while useful, it isn't needed. The mods merely have to listen to the community on such matters. Still, I support this nomination, if the subject would like to run for temporary moderatorship

Comment: I have arrived! I guess I should check on the meta more often ;)
I am currently easing myself into activities like review, and would be happy to expand this into being a mod.

Comment: @JamesWootton Let me give you the same advice as I gave to M. Stern: With your rep, you can easily assist in community moderation even if you fail to get elected. If you're uncertain how to do that, you can ask me (or others) in [chat]. I really hope that failing to get elected doesn't dampen your enthusiasm. Remember, the mods are more of a failsafe than anything else. Most moderation and quality control is done by the community!

Answer (score 5):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I'm self nominating. I've been working on quantum information theory (not exactly computing) for several years now. I like the Q&A format of stackexchange with its communities. I would love to see quantum computing SE to become a success.
Sometimes I was shocked to see extremely good questions down-voted a lot and even closed. I appreciate how motivated some of the younger folks are, but I think we should relax and stay calm! :) And we should keep a friendly and welcoming attitude to newcomers.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted, you seem to have a fair high rep relative to a lot of other users and are active on Meta and Regular

Comment: @frogeyedpeas One reason could be that the amount community moderation of M. Stern is not that high and the fact that James, another expert, is already running. I do think that 1 expert would be nice, but 2 isn't needed and hence the choice goes to candidates more active in community moderation (and more experienced in SE).

Comment: Nevertheless, I appreciate your efforts, M. Stern. With your rep, you can easily assist in community moderation if you fail to get elected. If you're uncertain how to do that, you can ask me (or others) in [chat]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

Hello, I am nominating myself to be a moderator pro-tempore.
I am a student from Germany and I program in my free time. I also  read a lot of books, my primary (science-related) reading interests are mathematics and physics and therefore I am interested in building and moderating this site.

#### Activity

At the time of writing, I am the third-most active user on meta (10 posts).
I have completed a total of sixteen reviews (plus one on meta), created the Moderation-request chat room and I am active in the Tag-watch chatroom.

---

I have currently moderation abilities on an other non-StackExchange site and I found out that I really like using moderation tools/features.

That is why I would like to be on of your moderators pro-tempore.

Comment: I would like to note that I have now [21](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/11/mee?tab=activity&sort=reviews) reviews and more coming

Comment: FYI: I have **41** (plus one on meta makes 42) reviews now.

Answer (score -8):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I have been requested to make a more serious proposal. Very well.

Although it seems unlikely that it now will amount a lot, I'm self-nominating. Hi!

First, of all let me talk about the past and my mistakes:

#### Mistakes made and regretted:

I've mostly let myself go and got into heated arguments on pointless issues. That was stupid. I intend to learn from this and not happen again.

Now, for the positive points:

#### Activity status:

- Asks questions that are well-received
- Active in general
- Tries to ask questions (in the comments) to improve questions and answers
- Expertise in CS (turns out to be a bit rare here)
- Main (QC) site 'impact' ~568
- Meta (QC) 'impact' ~467

#### Community modding:

- I attempt to recruit people.
- I welcome and try to assist new people.
- I edit tag excerpts.
- I edit questions.
- I edit a lot.

### Small malus

- My answers aren't well received. Ah well, I don't have much of them, anyway.

### Who are you?

Want a mod that can't make any new mistakes because he's made them all? Pick me. 
But more serious:

Who I am? I'm a masters' student in math at Eindhoven university. I've done my bachelors' in Math+CS. I specialize in Algorithms, Discrete Mathematics, Formal Methods (model checking, formal proof verification, etc). I do like to dive deep into game theory, though. In particular, I'd like to analyze (board) games with mathematics and CS and improve them.

As for my interest in QC, well I read Aaronsson's blog and like it. That's about it, really. But some problems in QC are actually problems in CS (sometimes already solved!)

I intend to get a PhD soonish. Don't worry, pro tempore  will be over before I'm even going to look for a PhD!

Comment: I apologize for the previous version to be not serious enough or somehow offensive. If that is the main reason for your downvote, I hope you can take the time to read again. Thank you.

Comment: Down votes may also be for things like your comments on Blue's post, your fights with others etc. With a requirement for moderators to calm conflict etc., how do you think you will manage this.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Oh, I am aware that my history is a minus, I in fact mention that at the start! But I've edited in reponse to a comment in chat that this wasn't serious enough, so I'd thought I'd mention it