# We are in public beta!

Tags: discussion, community

## We have made it to public beta!

First of all: **Congratulations** to everyone involved in the building and development of this site.

Now, as we are in public beta, there are some new challenges to solve, but I am pretty sure we are going to manage them:

1. We are probably going to get a lot of new users who will be not so familiar with this site as we are. *It is our task to help them!*
2. The reputation limits for the privileges have increased. This means that we have less/no users again that have access to the high moderation privileges. Good news is that we will have [pro-tempore moderators](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117/accepting-nominations-who-should-moderate-this-site) soon that will help the community team out.
3. We need **even more avid users** and **great contents** to make this site really succeed. That is why we should always monitor our [area51 stats](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106955/quantum-computing).
4. **Do not make rules for the sake of making rules**. We have been warned by Robert Cartaino that this community is making too many rules. Please follow this advice and *only make rules once we have a problem/posted question relating to this topic and **not** when you suppose that this could possibly happen*

   and probably the most important note:
5. **Stay active!** We haven't made it yet. We have just reached a new step. Continue participiating in the main page by *posting* questions and answers, *reviewing* posts in the queues, *suggesting*/*reviewing*/*making* edits and in meta by *defining* and *improving* our policies and community and *proposing* all the great ideas you might have.

> More information about the site lifecycle can be found in the [area51 faq](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) and in [this meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites?lq=1).

Comment: Congratulations! I'm fairly new around here, and I know practically nothing about Qcomputing, but I'm learning and hope to help around!

Answer (score 5):

I checked our Stats then checked here to see if the Search turned up anything before posting - your question is all that came up. We are ahead in a single category.

It looks like we would benefit from more Q&A, the rest should come on their own. We need to put in a bit more work if this site is to be viewed as a success.

---

**Quantum Computing**

Beta Q&A site for engineers, scientists, programmers, and computing professionals interested in quantum computing.

- 6.9 questions per day

10 questions per day on average is a healthy beta, 5 questions or fewer per day needs some work. A healthy site generates lots of good content to make sure users keep coming back.

- **97% answered**

90% answered is a healthy beta, 80% answered needs some work. In the beta it's especially important that when new visitors ask questions they usually get a good answer.

- 41 avid users - 1,753 total users

Every site needs a solid group of core users to assist in moderating the site. We recommend:

```
150 users with   200+ rep (currently 41 users with   200+ rep)
 10 users with 2,000+ rep (currently  0 users with 2,000+ rep)
  5 users with 3,000+ rep (currently  0 users with 3,000+ rep)
```

- 1.8 answer ratio

2.5 answers per question is good, only 1 answer per question needs some work. On a healthy site, questions receive multiple answers and the best answer is voted to the top.

- 237 visits/day

1,500 visits per day is good, 500 visits per day needs some work. A great site benefits people outside the community. Eventually, 90% of a site's traffic should come from search engines

Comment: For live version : https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106955/quantum-computing

Comment: For most of these 'requirements', this site is simply too small. But it is still young. Also note that not all these requirements are only guidelines and that sites have 'graduated' from beta without fulfilling all of them.

Comment: My recruiting drive has picked up a couple of people, and we have a couple of users with diamonds or over 200k rep elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

After one month, I thought the [live statistics of the quantum-computing beta](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106955/quantum-computing) are dropping dramatically. In fact, we can only know about questions/day: as indicated on the comment below, visits/day is not displayed correctly, due to a [relatively recent bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309064/traffic-isnt-updated-correctly-on-area51). Still, judging by our rythm of production of avid users and by the number of questions/day I'd venture we're not excelling on visits/day either.

Still: can we (or should we try to) do better? Should we try to prepare an ample battery of questions that we anticipate would be asked if&when the site becomes mainstream? What about offering bounties to attract existing users from physics, CS etc?

Comment: Some of this is/was hopefully a result of Easter (holidays). However, it's no longer Easter, so I was hoping that it would be picking up again by now :/ I don't see how offering bounties would attract people to the site or generate more questions, but it should help generate more answers

Comment: Update: the number of visits per day [is a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309064/349720)

Comment: Further update: the underlying issue is now fixed and the stats on area 51 will update themselves as per whatever process that is. Just so people know, we're in the realms of ~400 visits per day $\pm$ some number that depends on how long you're averaging over (so, 'needs some work' yet)